# Linq to Xml, '+' operation inside query expression

Tags: linq-to-xml, operations

```
var query = from k in xDoc.Descendants("product")
                               select
                                new
                                {

                                 KategoriKod =Convert.ToString( k.Element("cat1").Value) + Convert.ToString( k.Element("cat2").Value),

                                };
```

I want to take two elemens of an xml file by one variable. but I recieve this Error

> "'string' does not contain a definition for 'Value' "

any one help plz.?

Comment: Can you post the XML file for us to have a look at?

Comment: Unfortunately ! The XML file is a link that accessible just by User & Password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(
@"<root>
    <product>
        <cat1>ABC</cat1>
        <cat2>123</cat2>
    </product>
    <product>
        <cat1>XYZ</cat1>
    </product>
</root>");

    var query = from k in xDoc.Descendants("product")
                select new 
                {
                    KategoriKod = (string)k.Element("cat1") + (string)k.Element("cat2")
                };

    foreach(var k in query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(k);
    }
}
```

Here is the result:

{ KategoriKod = ABC123 }
{ KategoriKod = XYZ }
Press any key to continue . . .

Note that I used explicit conversion operator (casting elements to string) to avoid NullReferenceExceptions in when calling .Value on elements that do not exist.